# Why does my alias not work for Excel on Mac OSx?

Tags: excel, macos, bash, alias, darwin

I am in Darwin Kernel 14.3.0 and I want to create an alias for launching excel.  Here's what I added to my .bashrc file:

```
alias excel=‘/usr/bin/open /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Excel’
```

I am certain that it isn't a problem with running the `.bashrc` file because I have a print statement in it which works.

The error is:  `bash: alias: /Applications/Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft Excel’: not found`

Sorry if I'm missing something, but what could be the problem?  Thank you.

Comment: The `‘` is different that a single-quote char . i.e. `'`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have the wrong quote type:

```
alias excel='/usr/bin/open /Applications/Microsoft\ Office\ 2011/Microsoft\ Excel.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Excel'
```

Works fine (tested on OS X Yosemite)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the file you're supplying to `open` is the executable you need. Try running the same without aliases.

If it still doesn't work, you probably have some problems with escaping. Write `alias excel='/path/to/open` and then drag the executable file into the Terminal and don't forget the closing `'`.